# Fedora Remote Desktop

Tags: linux, windows-xp, remote-desktop

Wanted to switch my machine from Windows XP to Fedora Linux.

However we use Remote Desktop (to a Windows XP machine) at work.

Is there a way for Linux do Remote Desktop ?

Linux -> using Remote Desktop -> Windows XP machine

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different RDP clients for GNU/Linux.  I typically use grdesktop to remote into Windows machines.  It's actually a GUI frontend for rdesktop.

http://www.nongnu.org/grdesktop/

I don't use Fedora, but I'm sure it has a package available for it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to access your Fedora desktop from work, right? If so, you need VNC.  Here is a tutorial how to configure it: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/configure-vnc-server-in-fedora/ . You will also need a VNC client for windows, there are a lot of them, I use http://tigervnc.org/ .